# How to find the intersection of two lines given a point on each line and a parallel vector

Tags: python, algorithm, math, graphics, intersection

I need an algorithm that can find the intersection of two 2D lines. Each line will come in the form of **a point on the line and the dx/dy of a parallel vector**. I've tried parameterizing each line and solving the system of equations to solve for the parameterized variable which I could plug back into the parametric equation of the lines and get my x/y, but my attempt failed. Any ideas? I'm programming in Python but the language doesn't much matter.

Comment: "but my attempt failed" - if only there were *some* way that we could see your attempt? That would be useful information for us, yes? :-)

Comment: Just what do you mean by "dx/dy of a parallel vector"? Do you mean you are given the slope of the line (since parallel lines have the same slope), or a direction vector of the line, or something else? And we do need to see evidence of your work on the problem, if nothing else so we can see what failed.

Comment: @paxdiablo - wow so salty. But of course. I just didn't include it because it was long and bad. I started with  `x=x1+t1*dx1, y=y1+t1*dy1, x=x2+t2*dx2, y=y2+t2*dy2. after solving the system of equations I ended with t2=(x2dy1-x1dy1-y1y2dx1) / (dy2dy1-dx1dy2). ` When I tried using the values: `(x1,y1)=(0,0), (x2,y2)=(1,1), (dx1,dy1)=(1,0), (dx2,dy2)=(0,-1)` I got an 0 on the bottom of the t2 equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have to solve the following equation:

x = x<sub>0,a</sub>+dx<sub>a</sub>×t
y = y<sub>0,a</sub>+dy<sub>a</sub>×t
x = x<sub>0,b</sub>+dx<sub>b</sub>×u
y = y<sub>0,b</sub>+dy<sub>b</sub>×u

Or:

x<sub>0,a</sub>+dx<sub>a</sub>×t = x<sub>0,b</sub>+dx<sub>b</sub>×u
x<sub>0,a</sub>+dx<sub>a</sub>×t = x<sub>0,b</sub>+dx<sub>b</sub>×u

Now if you do some algebraic manipulation, you will find that:

t=dy<sub>b</sub>×(x<sub>0,b</sub>-x<sub>0,a</sub>)-dx<sub>b</sub>×(y<sub>0,b</sub>-y<sub>0,a</sub>)/d
u=dy<sub>a</sub>×(x<sub>0,b</sub>-x<sub>0,a</sub>)-dx<sub>a</sub>×(y<sub>0,b</sub>-y<sub>0,a</sub>)/d; where
d=dx<sub>a</sub>×dy<sub>b</sub>-dx<sub>b</sub>×dy<sub>a</sub>

Now it is thus only a matter to determine either `t` or `u` (you do not have to calculate both), and plug then into the formula above. So

```
def intersect(x0a,y0a,dxa,dya,x0b,y0b,dxb,dyb):
    t = (dyb*(x0b-x0a)-dxb*(y0b-y0a))/(dxa*dyb-dxb*dya)
    return (x0a+dxa*t,y0a+dya*t)
```

If the `d` in the equation (the denominator) is equal to zero, this means there is no intersection (the two lines are parallel). You can decide to alter the function and for instance return `None` or raise an exception in such case.

If you test it, for instance with a vector (1,0) offset and direction (0,1); and a vector with offset (0,2) and direction (1,1); you get the not very surprising result of:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def intersect(x0a,y0a,dxa,dya,x0b,y0b,dxb,dyb):
...     t = (dyb*(x0b-x0a)-dxb*(y0b-y0a))/(dxa*dyb-dxb*dya)
...     return (x0a+dxa*t,y0a+dya*t)
... 
>>> intersect(1,0,0,1,0,2,1,1)
(1.0, 3.0)
```

Comment: If I could upvote your answer 10 times I would. Thank you very much.